# Do not 'Auto Hide' dock on Cinema Display

Tags: macos

I have my dock preferences to auto-hide. When I plug in my Cinema Display it works as expected: the dock hides when the mouse isn't hovering over it. Is it possible to disable this functionality ONLY on the Cinema Display and keep it happening on the macbook?

For clarification: When my cinema display is plugged in I should be able to see the dock at all times on my cinema display, but it should still auto hide on macbook screen.

Comment: What Mode do you use the Cinema Display in (e.g. dual display extended or video mirroring)? If it's dual display extended, are you only using certain apps on the Cinema Display? If so, which ones?

Comment: I'm using it as dual display extended

Comment: In that case, are you wanting the dock active on both displays, or just one?

Comment: I want the dock always showing on my external display, and I want it to autohide on the internal display

Comment: Do you still want to be able to access the dock on the internal display (while the monitor is plugged in)?

Comment: Yes it should still do that. I want to be able to access the dock on the internal display. It should just autohide when the mouse isn't hovering over it.